# jQuery round function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I round the number using jQuery?

If the number is 3168 I want to print it as 32.
Or if the number is 5233 the result should be 52.

How can I do that?
Should I use the `Math.round` function?

Comment: So, by round, you mean divide by 100 and round?

Comment: the [jquery basic arithmetic plugin](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) can do this, and more.

Comment: @webarto, please refrain from creating joke tags.

Comment: @Charles yeah, sorry, but not sure it is a joke... I hope you understand.

Comment: http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-jquery

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, you should use Math.round (after dividing by 100).

jQuery is a library for DOM traversal, event handling and animation built on top of JavaScript. It doesn't replace JavaScript and doesn't reimplement all its basic functions.

Comment: see also Math.ceil() and Math.floor()

Answer (score 13):

```
var num = 3168;
$('#myElement').text(Math.round(num/100));
```

I assume you mean divide by 100, then round? Or did you mean to have decimal places? (In which case, remove the `/100` portion)

Also, this is just basic JavaScript. As another user mentioned, jQuery is to work with the document itself, not to perform math operations.

---

And here is a snippet from the jQuery math library<sup>1</sup>:

```
(function($){
  $.round = Math.round;
})(jQuery);

$.round(3168 / 100) // 32
$.round(5233 / 100) // 52
```

<sup>**1** *Meant for humor only--this kind of functionality is provided out-of-the-box by JavaScript itself.*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function jqROund(a) {
     return Math.round(a/100);
    }
</script>



    <input type='text' id='numba' value='3168'>
    <input type='button' onclick="alert( jqRound($('#numba').val() )  );">
```

The Math.round method does exactly you want and does not only ceil, or floor. It will round it to the nearest Integer.

Comment: -1 for creating a separate function for something so easy (it **shouldn't** be called jQRound, anyway), and using inline JS (`onclick` attribute).

Comment: the guy is trying to teach  something to the noob! Its a perfect example.

Comment: can you believe this guy? I put it in a function because the inside of that function is the answer to his question. Its called separation of concerns. The task is to answer someones question, not impress everyone else how well you can code, and use javascript naming conventions.

Comment: Stay calm, at least @Nyuszika7H left a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the javascript Number object you can use the `toFixed()` method. I'm assuming those numbers are missing the decimal point. If not, divide by 100 and as above.

Comment: This is the most useful answer in what I guess is the most common rounding scenario - wanting to present a number on screen with a sensible number of DPs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one :) `roundMe(1.2345, 4)`

```
function roundMe(n, sig) {
    if (n === 0) return 0;
    var mult = Math.pow(10, sig - Math.floor(Math.log(n < 0 ? -n: n) / Math.LN10) - 1);
    return Math.round(n * mult) / mult;
 }
```