# How to round an integer number (keeping multiples of 5 as they are)

Tags: javascript

I want to round an integer number, but keep multiples of 5 as they are instead of rounding either up or down.

In the first case if it is 35, after split 30 and 5, 5<=5 so the result should be 35.
In the second case if it is 37, after split 30 and 7, 7>5 so the result should be 40.

Can anyone help on this? I wish to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: What have you ried so far?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to round the number to the nearest equivalent of 5?

Comment: This looks more like some kind of rounding function and not a split function you are looking for.

Comment: I think what you want to do is to "round" the number up or down to the next multiplier of 5.

Comment: jquery is a library mostly designed for manipulating the DOM, and doesn't include math functions. What you're doing has nothing to do with it.

Comment: what i have tried and explain more u r question

Comment: There's a very similar question asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908552/jquery-round-function) It has some interesting answers. In particular, the mention that jQuery is a library for DOM manipulation. I don't think there's a round function in jQuery, and you might be better off using the basic javascript features

Comment: I edited the question; if you want 36 to be rounded to 35 instead of 40, feel free to correct my edits; the question is unclear.

Comment: So you always want to round _up_ to the nearest multiple of 5, never _down?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....I hope this is what you are looking for..

```
 function getVal(x) {

    return Math.round(x% 10 > 5 ? Math.round(x/10)*10: Math.round(x/10)*10+5);


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! i got my own solution for this!!

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
var n = 33;
Math.round(n/5)*5;
```

Comment: Thank you!! i found how to convert this into my needs.

Comment: Its not working for me!! Thanks for your help.. I found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(x % 10 > 5) {                                
    y=Math.round(x/10)*10;
} else {
    y=Math.round(x/5)*5;
}
```

where x - input; y - output